# Flutter doctor says `Android Studio ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version`

Tags: macos, flutter, android-studio

Flutter doctor says `Android Studio ✗ Unable to find bundled Java version`
I then downloaded and installed JDK from here for `mac M1`, `https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#jdk17-mac` , `arm` version.

I got jdk path with `java -version` and got `java version` `"17.0.1"`.

Got the path with `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` , `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home`

opened `.zhsrc` in a text editor and added the following

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/prettygirl/FlutterSDK/flutter/bin"
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home"
```

then ran the `flutter doctor` again, and it still shows the error mentioned above.

*Computer: M1 Mac-mini (silicon) macOS monterey*,
*Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Canary 4*

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on my Mac (also an M1).
I just downloaded the JDK from the java website itself and everything was ok after that.

Comment: did the same as first few steps, that didn't solve it, so I posted a question here.

Comment: In your terminal, type `which flutter`.
It could be that you have two different downloaded versions of flutter on the machine

Comment: If you get a `flutter not found`, it means that the local path is conflicting with another downloaded version of flutter